# phpseclib callback after exec

Tags: ssh, ffmpeg, phpseclib

From my website ( using symphony 3.3 ) I use **$ssh->exec** to ask to an other serveur to transcode video ( using ffmpeg ).
I work good but I have a problem.

After the transcoding operation, I get from the second server informations ( using **$sft->get** )about the transcoding in log file generated by ffmpeg ( using > at the end of the CLI ) and want to see the result in my web page.

The problem is : when I call **$sft->get** to get the informations the process is not finish ( it can take several minutes ). 
So how can the website know that the process is finish on the second server?
I try **$ssh->exec( $cli, 'callbak' );** without success ( callback work but come too early ).

If somebody understand my problem and know a solution, please tell me!
phpseclib is very good package I want to keep it.
best regards

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

You might have more success if you do something like this:

```
$ssh->write("[command]\n");
$ssh->read('[prompt]');

$ssh->get('/path/to/file');
```

`$ssh->read` will block until it reads the prompt in stdout. ie. it'll block until `[command]` has finished executing.